# Use multiprocess for boto3 s3 upload_fileobj causes SSLError

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-multiprocessing

In AWS Lambda with runtimes python3.9 and boto3-1.20.32, I run the following code,

```
s3_client = boto3.client(service_name="s3")
s3_bucket = "bucket"
s3_other_bucket = "other_bucket"

def multiprocess_s3upload(tar_index: dict):

    def _upload(filename, bytes_range):

        src_key = ...

        # get single raw file in tar with bytes range
        s3_obj = s3_client.get_object(
            Bucket=s3_bucket,
            Key=src_key,
            Range=f"bytes={bytes_range}"
        )

        # upload raw file
        # error occur !!!!!
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(
            s3_obj["Body"],
            s3_other_bucket,
            filename
        )

    def _wait(procs):
        for p in procs:
            p.join()
    
    processes = []
    proc_limit = 256  # limit concurrent processes to avoid "open too much files" error
    for filename, bytes_range in tar_index.items():
        # filename = "hello.txt"
        # bytes_range = "1024-2048"
       
        proc = Process(
            target=_upload,
            args=(filename, bytes_range)
        )
        proc.start()
        processes.append(proc)
        
        if len(processes) == proc_limit:
            _wait(processes)
            processes = []

    _wait(processes)
```

This program is extract partial raw files in a tar file in a s3 bucket, then upload each raw file to another s3 bucket. There may be thousands of raw files in a tar file, so I use multiprocess to speed up s3 upload operation.

And, I got the exception in a subprocess about SSLError for processing the same tar file randomly. I tried different tar file and got the same result. Only the last one subprocess threw the exception, the remaining worked fine.

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/response.py", line 441, in _error_catcher
  yield
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/response.py", line 522, in read
  data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 463, in read
  n = self.readinto(b)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 507, in readinto
  n = self.fp.readinto(b)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
  return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1242, in recv_into
  return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1100, in read
  return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2633)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/var/task/main.py", line 144, in _upload
  s3_client.upload_fileobj(
File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 540, in upload_fileobj
  return future.result()
File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
  return self._coordinator.result()
File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
  raise self._exception
File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 269, in _main
  self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/upload.py", line 588, in _submit
  if not upload_input_manager.requires_multipart_upload(
File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/upload.py", line 404, in requires_multipart_upload
  self._initial_data = self._read(fileobj, threshold, False)
File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/upload.py", line 463, in _read
  return fileobj.read(amount)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/response.py", line 82, in read
  chunk = self._raw_stream.read(amt)
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/response.py", line 544, in read
  raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
  self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/response.py", line 452, in _error_catcher
  raise SSLError(e)

urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2633)
```

According to this 10-years-ago similar question [Multi-threaded S3 download doesn't terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441412/multi-threaded-s3-download-doesnt-terminate), the root cause might be boto3 s3 upload use a non-thread-safe library for sending http request. But, the solution doesn't work for me.

I found a boto3 [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2462) about my question. This the problem has disappeared without any change on the author part.

> Actually, the problem has recently disappeared on its own, without any (!) change on my part. As I thought, the problem was created and fixed by Amazon. I'm only afraid what if it will be a thing again...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to boto3 documentation about multiprocessing ([doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html#multithreading-or-multiprocessing-with-resources)),

> Resource instances are not thread safe and should not be shared across threads or processes. These special classes contain additional meta data that cannot be shared. It's recommended to create a new Resource for each thread or process:

My modified code,

```
def multiprocess_s3upload(tar_index: dict):

    def _upload(filename, bytes_range):

        src_key = ...

        # get single raw file in tar with bytes range
        s3_client = boto3.client(service_name="s3")   # <<<< one clien per thread
        s3_obj = s3_client.get_object(
            Bucket=s3_bucket,
            Key=src_key,
            Range=f"bytes={bytes_range}"
        )

        # upload raw file
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(
            s3_obj["Body"],
            s3_other_bucket,
            filename
        )

    def _wait(procs):
        ...
    
    ...
```

It seems that no SSLError exception occurs.